# Make an object from a string in node js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, string

I am sending the string from AngularJS to NodeJS in following form.

```
"{↵obj:{↵one:string,↵two:integer↵}↵}"//request object from browser console
```

I want to convert this string in object and use its properties.for this the server side code is following:

```
var data=req.body.data.replace(/"/g,"");
var str=data.replace(/\n/g," ");
//res.json(str) // returning "{ obj:{ one:string, two:integer } }"
try {
var obj=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(str)).replace(/"/g,"");
res.json(obj);//returning same "{ obj:{ one:string, two:integer } }"
} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
}
```

I want to get **['users']** by  **Object.keys[obj]** or by any other method want to access the properties of this object.but failed to achieve this.

Many solutions like [This](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwjykq6Jp77QAhUMKsAKHWxbC9kQFggxMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F14028259%2Fjson-response-parsing-in-javascript-to-get-key-value-pair&usg=AFQjCNESEAp732pblpJUyvzUxSni4HAy7Q&sig2=0VsjNNOKRAj2rF6SoAuAmQ&bvm=bv.139782543,d.d2s&cad=rja) couldn't be helpful.any suggestion here??

Comment: Why are you removing quotes and newlines? If it's valid JSON then all you need to do is call `JSON.parse()` on `req.body.data`.

Comment: It seems that this is not a valid JSON

Comment: it is not parsing req.body.data directly.by doing this JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body.data))   the answer is "{\nobj:{\none:string,\ntwo:integer\n}\n}".....still properties are not accessible

Comment: @ThomasThiebaud error after json.parse shows this but how can i validate this json in case.???can u please explain?

Answer (score 2):

All you need is `JSON.parse` to convert string to object.

Something like this:

```
var jsonString='{"obj":{"one":"string","two":"integer"}}';
console.log(JSON.parse(jsonString));
```

Output:

```
{ obj: { one: 'string', two: 'integer' } }
```

Comment: just json.parse is creating error as unexpected token.

Comment: Show the console output.

Comment: this is req.body.data   {
obj:{
one:string,
two:integer
}
}         not like json object.and this is console output.SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 2
    at Object.parse (native)

Comment: That's because it's not a proper JSON string. This is json object.
A json string would be this :
'{"obj":{"one":"string","two":"integer"}}';

Comment: okay so is this an object string?? can we convert it into simple object instead of json?

Comment: It's an object already. You can access the data directly. :)
Try this :

var a = { obj:{ one:string, two:integer } } and you can access the data obj like : 
console.log(a.obj)

Comment: no this is not simply the object.it is giving undefined on this.var obj=req.body.data;
 console.log(str.obj)

Comment: it is looking like an object but it is still a string.

Comment: When you are doing var obj=req.body.data; then do this instead console.log(obj.obj)

Comment: Can you also check whats the output for : ```typeof obj```

Comment: console.log(typeof(obj)) is giving string and console.log(obj.obj); isgiving undefined.

Answer (score 0):

For example my raw data is like this :

```
var raw_data = 
    {
        "ok": true,
        "user": {
            "id": "U89MZ4PV2",
            "team_id": "T895HCY8H",
            "name": "hyosoka187",       
        }
    }
```

then just use `JSON.parse(raw_data, true);`. So

```
var real_data = JSON.parse(raw_data, true);
console.log(real_data.user.name);
```

Result :

```
hyosoka187
```

NOTE :
Output of `JSON.parse(raw_data, true) :`

```
{
    ok: true,
    user: {
        id: 'U89MZ4PV2',
        team_id: 'T895HCY8H',
        name: 'hyosoka187',       
    }
}
```